# What is required to use NetworkManager user connections without an X session?

Tags: command-line, network-manager

I want to use my NetworkManager user connections from console without starting an X session. There seem to be some dependencies:

> ```
> ~/ > nmcli con list                                                                                                                                
> ** (process:4418): WARNING **: fetch_connections_done: error fetching user connections: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings was not provided by any .service files.                                                                                                                                         
> NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                                                      
> NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL
> ```

After logging in to Gnome nmcli works as expected:

> ```
> ~/ > nmcli con list                                                                                            
> NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                  
> NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                  
> Home                      5...2   802-11-wireless   user     Tue 12 Oct 2010 06:23:12 PM EEST
> LAN                       0...8   802-3-ethernet    user     Wed 13 Oct 2010 12:11:36 AM EEST
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/nmcli.1.html):

> User sessions: For this case, nmcli can talk to nm-applet to find
>              user connections.  It can still talk directly to NetworkManager for
>              manipulating these connections.  As nmcli doesn't have direct
>              access to user configuration data in GConf, nm-applet handles that
>              itself.  That may, for example, cause the applet to pop up keyring
>              dialogs when secrets are needed.

From my understanding this means you cannot see user connections without having nm-applet running (it works fine for system wide connections).

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that. After some experimenting it seems to come down to Gnome Keyring being unavailable, so nm-applet wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think nmcli is included in Network-Manager since version 0.8... Just install network-manager and type in `man nmcli` to see how nmcli works.